# How can I get userId in Api project for logged user?

Tags: identityserver4

I have Api project and IdentityServer project. User is logged in IdentityServer. How can I get userId of logged user in Api project?

**I am authenticated in identity server but I don't have access to api, I see 401 error (unauthorized) when I am trying to call the api method, why?**

I have added in Api to Startup.cs in ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "url to identity server";
    options.ApiName = "test";
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("defaultpolicy", builder =>
    {
        builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

In Configure method:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Api controller:

```
[Authorize("defaultpolicy")]
public class ApplicationsController : ControllerBase
{
....
}
```

Comment: In the oidc flows the access token contains a sub claim, that's the id of the user. Any flow, except for credentials and device flow contain the sub claim.

Comment: The `client` supports a certain flow, e.g. hybrid for mvc. The api is the resource to protect (covers one or more scopes). IdentityServer allows the client to route a user to the login page and returns an `access token` (allows the `client` to access the api _on behalf of_ the user) containing the `sub` claim. If configured, the identity token is provided on login along with the access token. It contains only the sub claim and can be used to redirect the user back to the client after logout. Use the access token to contact the userinfo endpoint if you need additional claims.

Comment: I have added setup in below answer.

Comment: Ok I have deleted the answer.

Comment: How do you get the information from the Api? Can you show your code? You'll need to send the access token in the header of the request.

Comment: I simply call the api url. How can I get access token?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your [Authorize] protected Api Controller Method you could use:

`var userId = User?.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`